# First and Last in SAS and R

Tags: r, if-statement, sas

I am working on converting a SAS code to R but I am having trouble replicationg the **IF First. & Last.** command in R.
The SAS command is -

```
Data A;
Set B;
BY CompID, Id, Date;
IF First.Date;
run;
```

My understanding is that only the earliest date for a CompID, ID and Date combination is chosen and output into data A. Am I right?

I am aware of the **duplicated** command in R but if I use the following code -

```
A <- B[!duplicated(B$Date),]
```

I get lesser observations than my SAS output. Am I missing on something here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construction in R could be (since there is also a `duplicated.data.frame` function):

```
A <- B[!duplicated(B[ c('CompID', 'Id', 'Date') ] ) ,]
```

To duplicate a .Last operation, look at the help page for duplicate and I think you will find some sort of `fromLast` parameter, but I always need to check its spelling.

The construction: "I get lesser observations than ..." sounds wrong to me, but I have not traveled in all the English speaking countries. At least in the US,  I think "fewer" or " a lower count" would read a bit easier.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize you could do this with a combination of columns! This solves my problem. And as for 'lower' vs. 'lesser', I am not sure of the usage..

Comment: Hi! I have been thinking about the answer and I have a doubt. The BY statement sorts the data by the two variables and then picks out the first value right? SO in the example given, it will sort the data by the 3 columns and pick the row for the earliest Date value right? In that case, if I sort my data in R and do !duplicated(date), will that be the same?

Answer (score 1):

First of all the statement `BY CompID, Id, Date;`  should not have any commas in it.

Secondly, `A <- B[!duplicated(B$Date),]` is not the equivalent of the SAS code you posted.

The correct equivalent would be:

```
Data A;
Set B;
BY Date;
IF First.Date;
run;
```

> My understanding is that only the earliest date for a CompID, ID and
>   Date combination is chosen and output into data A. Am I right?

Your understanding is correct.

Comment: Thanks! The commas were my typos, thanks to R. WHat would be the R equivalent? I was thinking a SQLDF statement like 'Select compId, id, min(date) from B group by compId, id'). Would that be right?